# GET https://franklpjr.github.io/src/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, deployment, console, vite

The navigator shows this message GET https://franklpjr.github.io/src/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 to the main file, i dont know how to fix it

Somebody could help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JCD Armazém</title>
    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <script>window.rwbp={email:'jcdarmazemdotijolo@gmail.com',phone:'5592992978550',message:'Olá, seja bem vindo ao JCD Armazém! Como podemos te ajudar?',lang:'pt-BR'}</script>
    <script defer async src='https://duz4dqsaqembt.cloudfront.net/client/whats.js'></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
      crossorigin></script>

    <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
  
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is related to **GitHub page**. Check GitHub action, it is possible you did something's wrong configuration.